# How can I get the X509Store from a UWP app using WinJS?

Tags: uwp, x509certificate, winjs, x509

I'm writing an UWP app in WinJS that needs to retrieve the user X.509 certificate.

I've found examples of how to do that using .NET Framework and they reference the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` namespace. In UWP I can access the `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates` namespace, but I can't find how to get a `Windows.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`.

I also can't find a reference to `X509Certificates` for UWP in `learn.microsoft.com`.

Is that a UWP limitation, or am I doing something wrong in WinJS?

Comment: What did you want to do by using this X.509 certificate?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I need to authenticate an HTTP request.

Comment: There's no way to get certificate by using js code. The UWP app(winjs) actually is a web app. For general web application, the browser will help you do this operation, you do not need to do this operation.

Comment: It isn’t a web app, it is a desktop app. We wished to make it a UWP app using JS, and it seems that I can access certificates using the `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates` namespace, I just can’t access the X.509 certificates.